# Populate hidden field with javascript array

Tags: javascript, django, forms

I'm using django to submit a list of graphics/titles to a player in a table like this...

```
<table>

    {% for title in titles %}

    <tr><form action="{% url 'show_title' %}" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}

    <td width="1%"><input type="image" src="{% static 'css/img/CG-Play.png' %}" border="0" alt="Submit" /></td>
    <td width="20%">{{title.name }}</td><td width="78%">{{title.occupation }}</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" class="delete" name="delete" value="{{ title.id }}" /></td>
    <input type="hidden" name="f0" value="{{ title.name }}" />
    <input type="hidden" name="f1" value="{{ title.occupation }}" />
    </tr>
    </form>
    {% endfor %}

</table>
```

included in each form is a submit image/button that sends the correct info in the hidden fields to the player. Also included is a checkbox with the class "delete" that I want to access in another form to delete the chosen/checked titles.

Due to the HTML layout, the form for delete is in a different location, so I want to use javascript to gather the "{{ title.id }}" data present in the form above, and send the data in a hidden field in form Nr. 2

```
<form action="{% url 'delete_titles' %}" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="hidden" id="input_form_1" name="java_array" value="java_values" />
    <button type="submit" class="actionbutton deletebutton" name="delete_titles" onclick="return confirm('Delete (' + $(':checkbox:checked').length + ') title(s) - Are you sure?')" >Delete Titles</button>
 </form>
```

I tried with a script like this which is loaded in the header and almost does what I want, but it only updates the array when I refresh the page of course.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    var java_values = [];
    $(".delete:checked").each(function(){
        java_values.push($(this).val());
    });
    $('#input_form_1').val(JSON.stringify(java_values));
    console.log(java_values);
});
</script>
```

How do I update the values in the array?

Comment: both forms are in different pages ? and you want to fetch the selected checkboxes of one form on other `html form` which is on some other page ? right  ?

Comment: No both forms are on the same page - so I just need to get the checked boxes from one form and submit it in a hidden field in the other.

Answer (score 0):

You can store `title.id` as a session variable.

```
request.session['title_id'] = title.id
```

More info here: (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/http/sessions/)[https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/http/sessions/]

Comment: But the checked boxes are client side so how would a session variable know which boxes were checked from static HTML without submitting a form?